# Python: TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python, string, save, spyder

What I am doing wrong here? Please any suggestions. Thanks

I am trying to write out my data, but it kept giving me an error..Here is my code:

```
with open(output,'wb') as f:

    f.write(b'Apple Data\n7\nApple Number\nE, m\nN, m\nE, m\nB, percent\nF, percent\nFa Code\n')
    for i in range(new_ndata):
        f.write(str(nn[i])+' '+str(x[i])+' '+str(y[i])+' '+str(n[i])+' '+str(nb[i])+' '+str(nf[i])+' '+str(nfa[i])+'\n')
```

Comment: there is a problem when you're converting to str and did you know that you can use format to format a string?

Comment: if i knew the solution would never bother...

Comment: try putting `byte` in front of the string and please use `format`:

    f.write(b"{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6}\n".format(str(ndh[i]), str(ncoordx[i]), str(ncoordy[i]), str(nelev[i]), str(nbit[i]), str(nfines[i]), str(nfac[i]))

Comment: @minitoto: the `bytes` type deliberately does not have a `format` method in Python 3 (it does in Python 2, but only because `bytes` is a alias for `str`).

Comment: How do i know which version op uses

Comment: @minitoto: the error described would not come up in Python 2.

Comment: Note that using `str.format` *is* a good suggestion, it just doesn't work directly with `bytes` objects. You should do the formatting with `str` instance, then encode to `bytes` later (either explicitly, as in my answer, or let the file object do it for you, as in Pyncha's answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is a Python 3 issue, and has to do with how in Python 3 (unlike Python 2), the `str` type is Unicode, rather than encoded bytes.

Your first `write` call correctly passes a `bytes` instance (the `b` prefix on the quoted string gives this away). Your second call, however, passes a `str` instance (concatenated from a bunch of smaller strings).

You need to encode that string to bytes before writing it to a binary file. Or alternatively, open the file in text mode, and let it encode the string for you this will require changing the first `write` to send a string, rather than pre-encoded `bytes`).

For the former, try something like:

```
f.write((str(ndh[i])+' '+str(ncoordx[i])+' '+str(ncoordy[i])+' '+
         str(nelev[i])+' '+str(nbit[i])+' '+str(nfines[i])+' '+
         str(nfac[i])+'\n').encode("utf-8"))
```

The extra bit is way at the end, so I've wrapped the lines at a couple convenient spots (it's allowed inside a parenthesized expression). I've picked the `"utf-8"` encoding somewhat arbitrarily. You may want to use something different (e.g. ASCII or one of the many other encodings available). Not all encodings can encode all Unicode strings. (You could also probably express the big string concatenation more concisely with a single `str.format` call, but that's unrelated to the encoding issue.)